# How do I remove and prevent calluses from weightlifting?

Tags: weightlifting, gym, callus

When I am lifting weights, I noticed that there are calluses that form at the base of the fingers. I am fine with them but sometimes the start to dry up and peel.

Is there a way to remove them?

Also, I surmised that wearing gloves while lifting weights will minimise the calluses but is there another way to prevent them without wearing gloves?

Comment: There's a ["tutorial" on Beast Skills](http://www.beastskills.com/tutorials/tutorials/50) on removing calluses. I haven't tried it, but the guy usually writes very good advice so it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well technically you're not gripping the bar right, but who does?
The top layers of calluses will eventually peel off, becoming a little smoother, but this cycle just keeps going.

So there are three ways to prevent calluses:

- Stop all pulling exercises – not a good option
- Wear gloves – not for me
- Or grip the bar slightly above your calluses

That's why I said you grip wrong. Open your palm and put your finger across the bottom of your calluses, your finger represents the bar. Now in a pulling exercise the bar or (finger) will push that skin towards your fingers; do this with your finger and you will see what I mean.
Now put your finger right above your calluses and curl your fingers over slightly and then slide your finger up. You're not pinching your skin between the bar and fingers now.
Basically grip the bar slightly above your calluses so your skin doesn't get pinched. We have a tendency to do this because it makes the bar thicker in our hand, giving a better grip but causing calluses.

One last note: when you can deadlift 600 pounds you do not want to pinch the skin in your grip it will tear your calluses away from hand.

Better strengthen your grip and practice better technique before you start pulling heavy.

Answer (score 4):

If you're lifting heavy, chalk can help by preventing the bar from slipping in your grip, which pulls on the skin. Most commercial gyms won't allow this, but you can do it in a home gym or a powerlifting-friendly gym.

If you really want to remove existing calluses, a pumice stone will do the trick.

Comment: If you grip wrong your already pulling on your skin. >_<